# Attempting to aggregate information from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm a total novice when it comes to writing macros/VB for Excel, and I'm getting really stuck on this problem.

Here is a sample of what I have

[image: 1]

And here is what I'm hoping for

[image: 2]

As you can see, I'm hoping to aggregate the individual scores and their comments for each `reviewer_id`, for each `appl_id`, while also pulling the AGGREGATE score for each `appl_id`. Sometimes there are no comments for scores, which seems to make it complicated. This table is about 2K rows in length, so doing this manually didn't seem like an option.

Comment: Pivot tables might get you some of the way ...

Comment: how many reviewer_ids do you have per appl_id? is it always only 1 or 2?

Comment: is it ok that you lose the reviewer_id in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will process the data as per your example. If you have more than 3 reviewers per appl_id then you need to change `mr`. You may also want to change the sheet and range that REF refers to.

```
Sub marine()

Dim REF As Range
Dim REF2 As Range
Set REF = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'location of start of data table set. Set this to the correct reference.

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Processed"

Set REF2 = Sheets("Processed").Range("A1")

' max number of reviewers
mr = 3

' set headers
REF2.Value = "appl_id"
For i = 1 To mr
 REF2.Offset(0, (i - 1) * 2 + 1).Value = "score_" & i
 REF2.Offset(0, (i - 1) * 2 + 2).Value = "comment_" & i
Next i
REF2.Offset(0, mr * 2 + 1).Value = "aggregate_score"

i = 1
a = 0
s = 0
Do While (REF.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "")
 appl_id = REF.Offset(i, 0).Value
 If (appl_id <> REF.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value) Then 'new apple_id
   a = a + 1
   s = 0
   REF2.Offset(a, 0).Value = appl_id 'set new apple_id row
 End If
 If (REF.Offset(i, 1).Value = "AGGREGATE") Then
   REF2.Offset(a, mr * 2 + 1).Value = REF.Offset(i, 2).Value 'set aggregate
 Else
   REF2.Offset(a, s + 1).Value = REF.Offset(i, 2).Value 'set score
   REF2.Offset(a, s + 2).Value = REF.Offset(i, 3).Value 'set comment
   s = s + 2
 End If

 i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```